# Why does ! && equal ||?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I recently came across a problem in which we were to find an equivalent boolean expression for 
`(x && !y)`
given a set of choices. While walking through a few of the examples my professor noted that 
`!(!x && y)` is not the correct answer because the ! distributes making this expression equivalent to `(x || !y)`, so the ! changes && to ||. Inversely, the correct answer was `!(!x || y)`.

I tried to play around with the truth tables for && and || and I cannot see why this would be true. Negating the results from the && truth table doesn't give results equal to ||. Negating the output of && would produce

```
    0 && 0 --> 0 !-> 1
    0 && 1 --> 0 !-> 1
    1 && 0 --> 0 !-> 1
    1 && 1 --> 1 !-> 0
```

I can see how the answer above is correct, I just don't understand why. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De Morgan's laws https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws are relevant.

They say:

```
I)   !(a && b) = (!a) || (!b)
II)  !(a || b) = (!a) && (!b)
```

where negating *and* means *or*ing both negations while negating *or* means *and* of both negations.

Let's replace a by (!x) and b by y in `II`:

```
II)  !((!x) || y) = (!(!x)) && (!y)
```

which gives

```
II)  !(!x || y) = x && (!y)
```

showing that ineed the correct equivalent is `!(!x || y)`.